# close expansion panels using output and input events for dynamically added components

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular10

Im pushing dynamically added componnets to an array "elements"

```
 this.elements.push({ view, component });
```

Each of the components has a mat-expansion-panel like:

```
 <mat-expansion-panel fxFlex="100" [expanded]="!closed" (opened)="emitOpened()" >
```

Inside each of these components there is an Input() closed and an event emitter panelOpened emitted when the panel is opened:

```
  emitOpened() {
    this.panelOpened.emit();
  }
```

When one of these component's expansion panel is opened , the panels of all other components should get closed .

```
  closeOtherQuestions() {
    this.elements
      .map((el) => el.component)
      .forEach((c) => {
        c.panelOpened.subscribe((open) => {
          this.elements
            .map((el) => el.component)
            .filter((item) => item !== c)
            .forEach((item) => (item.closed = true));
        });
      });
  }
```

Im trying to pass in closed after subscribing to the output event of each of these components .Right now its not working correctly . Im seeing that the subscription is triggering multiple times as it is placed inside a forEach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `combineLatest` in combination with `pairWise` to find the element in the array which should become closed. For this approach you would need to change `panelOpened` event to a `expansionChanged` event which holds the current state as a boolean.

```
emitOpened() {
    this.expansionChanged.emit(true);
  }

emitClosed() {
    this.expansionChanged.emit(false);
  }
```

Now you can do

```
combineLatest(this.elements.map(el => el.component.expansionChanged)).pipe(
  pairWise(),
  map(([prev, curr]) => curr.findIndex((el, i) => el && prev[i])),
).subscribe(
  index => this.elements[index].component.closed = true;
);
```